# jQuery Masonry not working.

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I had it working but for some reason it has just stopped working and I don't know what I have done.The box `divs` are floated left, I just don't know where I've gone wrong.

**Jquery**

```
var $container = $('.work');            
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){                 
   $container.masonry({
      itemSelector: '.box',
      isAnimated: true,
      columnWidth: 250                  
   });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="part-one" class="work">
   <div class="box col2"><img src="_assets/images/one.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
   <div class="box col2"><img src="_assets/images/two.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
   <div class="box col2"><img src="_assets/images/three.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
   <div class="box col2"><img src="_assets/images/four.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
   <div class="box col2"><img src="_assets/images/five.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.work {
   margin-left:98px;
   top:0;
   max-width:1600px;
   padding-bottom:100px;
   position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: can you please supply a fully non-working example?

Comment: just a guess, but does it work when you remove imagesLoaded() and do the masonry() part on document load?

Comment: No it doesn't, it has definitely pulled the scripts in, I checked with  firebug, I am at a total loss! I'll try and get a jsfiddle

Comment: Here is a quick fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/s8PhS/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove your `columnWidth` property and Masonry will use the width of the first item element. ([Docs](http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/options.html#columnwidth)).

**Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8PhS/14/). http://jsfiddle.net/s8PhS/14/**

If you resize the HTML container in JSFiddle it will also resize dynamically.
I also added some extra `<div>` elements for demo purposes and a `Odd Five element` with a different height, and you can see the masonry plugin kicks in and position's the elements perfectly.

So basically, remove the property `columnWidth: 250` and let Masonry pick it up dynamically.

In [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8PhS/14/), this seems to solve your problem.

---

**Just a tip**: I used this same jquery.masonry plugin recently, but also wanted to sort my elements, I found this amazing plugin called [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) which is amazing and much more customizable.

[Check out the Demo on the Homepage!](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be related to the masonry column width property and the space available to display the div. Trying to play with on your jsfiddle make thinking about that.
Good luck.